# Kotlin Gradle Spotless ktlint configuration

Tags: kotlin, gradle, code-formatting, ktlint, spotless

I currently use the following way to apply ktlint to my projects:

```
plugins{
    id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "6.7.2"
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless")

    spotless {
        kotlin {
            target("**/*.kt")
            ktlint("0.45.2")
        }
        kotlinGradle {
            target("*.gradle.kts", "additionalScripts/*.gradle.kts")
            ktlint("0.45.2")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to tweak some on the configurations so that the linter fits with what we want in the team. for example, set a max line length to 120.

For this, I found that we can do something like:
`ktlint("0.30.0").userData(mapOf("max_line_length" to "120"))`
in the build.gradle.kts file. However, as we go on adding more tweaks, this becomes very difficult to manage and copy from project to project, and the `spotlessApply` task fails to format the code and simply raises it as an issue during the build.Is it possible to get it to auto-format in this case?

ktlint itself supports the `.editorconfig` file for such configurations. How do I apply that with spotless?

Comment: It's not supported yet https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/142

Answer (score 1):

Three years later - but better late than never! - it works.

Starting in Spotless version `6.13.0` and ktlint versions `0.47.1` and `0.48.1` this behavior now works out of the box.

1. [Issue](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/142) where this has been tracked.
2. [PR](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/pull/1442) where this has been implemented.
3. [Plugin release](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/releases/tag/plugin-gradle%2F6.13.0) where the feature was first shipped.